# Java XOR Operator questions

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, xor

I have some questions about the XOR operator **^** in Java.

I always thought that Java does not have a logical XOR operator because several people told me **^** is bitwise.
Today I found some (unconfirmed) posts (without sources) saying **^** is overloaded in Java, working as a logical XOR for booleans and as a bitwise XOR e.g. for integers.

Which statement is true? Can anyone provide some reliable sources?

If **^** is overloaded, which types does it accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22) defines

> When both operands of an operator `&`, `^`, or `|` are of a type that is
>   convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type, binary numeric
>   promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> The type of the bitwise operator expression is the promoted type of
>   the operands.
>
> - For `^`, the result value is the bitwise exclusive OR of the operand values.

and

> When both operands of a `&`, `^`, or `|` operator are of type `boolean` or
>   `Boolean`, then the type of the bitwise operator expression is `boolean`.
>   In all cases, the operands are subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)
>   as necessary.
>
> - For ^, the result value is `true` if the operand values are different;
>     otherwise, the result is `false`.

There is no concept of overloading operators in Java.

Comment: I think it's OK to call the operator "overloaded" as just a general concept.  But of course you can't overload operators yourself the way you can in C++ or some other languages.

Comment: @ajb IMO If it's not in the language terminology. I'd avoid its use when talking about the language. There are two `^` operators in Java, one bitwise and one logical.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of ^ as bitwise XOR.

You should think of booleans as single bits with false=0 and true=1.

That second sentence has as much to do with your question as it does to do with thinking like a programmer!